# Is it possible to return data from webage to main server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

This may be a (and probably is) dumb question but I have been trying to set up a server that will work with http and websockets. I would like the result of a button press to change a value within the server which can then be sent across a websocket.

This is my main server code:

```
var express = require('express');                 
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware');
 req.testing = 'device-protocol';
 return next();
});

app.get('/button.htm', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "button.htm" );
});

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log("Message received from client: %s", msg);
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));              
    given, should query

  });
  console.log('socket', req.testing);
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

console.log("Test app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

And here is my button webpage:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8 /angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.showMe = false;
       $scope.myFunc = function() {
           $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;
       }
   });
  </script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myFunc()">Click Me!</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to hand back a variable from the webpage's button to the main server and have it continuously update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have `myFunc` to make a plain [http request](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to your server, in which it will receive a value and broadcast it through your websockets connection.